# OpenTracing inject/extract in Jaeger

Tags: java, opentracing, jaeger

I'm new to OpenTracing. Until now I was mainly working in house tracing tool. The server is not able to extract the span context.

```java
MultivaluedMap<String, String> rawHeaders = httpHeaders.getRequestHeaders();
final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String key : rawHeaders.keySet()) {
    if(key.contentEquals("deviceKey"))
        headers.put(key, rawHeaders.get(key).get(0));
}
Tracer.SpanBuilder spanBuilder;
try {
    SpanContext parentSpanCtx = tracer.extract(Format.Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new TextMapExtractAdapter(headers));
    if (parentSpanCtx == null) {
        spanBuilder = tracer.buildSpan(operationName);
    }

    else {
        spanBuilder = tracer.buildSpan(operationName).asChildOf(parentSpanCtx);
    }

}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    spanBuilder = tracer.buildSpan(operationName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

...

```
if(key.contentEquals("deviceKey"))
    headers.put(key, rawHeaders.get(key).get(0));
```

...

```
tracer.extract(Format.Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new TextMapExtractAdapter(headers))
```

You seem to be trying to extract a context based on a map containing only a key named `deviceKey`. Unless you are using a custom tracer, you should really be passing all HTTP headers to the `#extract()` method.